# Doesn't Lorentz transformation disprove aether?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, inertial-frames, history, aether

I am struggling to understand the reason behind why lorentz still believe in the aether theory after developing his transformation.

The aether frame is the frame by which all velocities should be measured from

However the transformation he devised, is a transformation that makes maxwells equations hold, for ALL frames. Meaning applying his transformation to another frame, and choosing v to be measured with respect to that frame, should still follow maxwells equations

So why was lorentz so caught up on the aether theory, when his transformation itself proved it was not necessary?

Unless my reasoning is wrong

Comment: Related on [HSM.se] (and may well answer your question):  [What did Einstein contribute to Special Relativity that hadn't already been done by Lorentz in 1904 and Poincaré in 1905?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/4941/)

Comment: Even SR does not rule out Aether completely https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_ether_theory#:~:text=Lorentz's%20initial%20theory%20was%20created,in%20motion%20in%20the%20aether.

Comment: The Lorentz transformation does not disprove aether, but only makes it relative and consequently undetectable, so its existence becomes irrelevant for relativity.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's mechanics assumed absolute space even though its rules obeyed Galilean relativity. The mathematics isn't physics: it's a story we tell about the physics.

Einstein's story was clearer than Lorentz's, but it was missing a mechanism for the weird effects of velocity on distances and time. Not really a problem for physics, but this kind of thing bothers some. Lorentz's story attributed those to interactions with the ether.

Of course, Minkowski came along and attributed the weird effects in Einstein's story to perspective in a weird geometry, so then there was a mechanism.